# Compact Framework WCF and gzip encoding

Tags: wcf, compact-framework

Before I go off and write way too much code, I want to check that I'm not reinventing a (freely) available wheel, and make sure that I can, in fact, read and use Google.

I have a Java web service I am calling from compact framework. I'm using the NetCFSvcUtil program with the Compact Framework powertools to generate the wrapper classes. I've convinced the group creating the service to not send me CSV-in-XML and instead send proper SOAP messages with gzip turned on.

And gzip on CF is where I run into the issue. The `HttpTransportBindingElement` doesn't emit the `accept-encoding` header on it's own. So, I either need to figure out someway to inject that header, rewrite a large part of the framework so I can add that header, or some unknown third option.

So, in short, how can I make the compact framework accept gzip?

EDIT:

This morning I tried running the WSDL through the wsdl tool, once I found it was quite simple to make the Web Service side of thing use compression (Setting `EnableDecompression` on the service proxy), made the suggestions listed by MSDN to get the generated code to compile on the device... and it's 30-40 seconds *slower* than the WCF call. A simple comparison seems to point at the the Web Service API being that much slower than the WCF API, so that option is ruled out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as it's not an answer, we ended up doing the whole thing with straight XML and WebRequests.